# Defining the "Go To App" button's URL

Tags: facebook, url, canvas

On the app profile page, how can the URL for the "Go To App" button be manually set?

So insted of going to the app's facebook canvas page, the user is taken direct to a different site.

much like on: http://www.facebook.com/Sendible?ref=ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a custom URL, that's the URL of their app - they don't have a canvas page, they have a site off-Facebook.

To answer your question, you can't set a custom URL, but if your app has a 'website' integration and no 'canvas' integration, that website is where the 'Go To App' button will go